# Cannot resolve data with UI router within angular component

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I'm having difficulty getting my resolve to correctly work with my angular components and UI router. For example, I'm defining a `goal` component:

```
// goal.component.js

import template from './goal.html';
import controller from './goal.controller';
import './goal.scss';

export default {
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {},
  template,
  controller
};
```

And I have the following `config` where I define the route and resolve, `data`, for this component:

```
// goal.config.js

export default ($stateProvider) => {
  'ngInject';

  $stateProvider
    .state('goal', {
      url: '/goals/goal/:uuid',
      component: 'goal',
      resolve: {
        data: () => {
          return Promise.resolve('data');
        }
      }
    });
};
```

And within the controller, I'm trying to access the `data` resolve but I continue to get the error that the `data` provider is not recognized:

```
// goal.controller.js

export default class GoalController {

  constructor($state, data) {
    'ngInject';
    console.log('>>>', data);
  }
}
```

ERROR: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: data`

Comment: Are you using that component anywhere else?

Comment: Which component? The `goal` one? If so, nope. If I did, would it matter? Curious...

Comment: Yes, because if you are using it elsewhere without resolving `data` you would get an `$injector:unpr` error